# TFS Server 2017 Error : The field <<name>> contains the value <<Value>> that is not in the list of supported values

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, workitem, azure-devops-rest-api

I have TFS/VSTS extension in which I manipulate work items using rest calls . I use same for create , change status and close work items. And I could successfully do this process in several environments which is including TFS 2015 , TFS 2017 and VSTS.

However when I try this same process to create work Items (success) and update (close and status changes) I got below error on my console. I am testing on TFS server 2017 in this particular test case.

```
Bad Request(400) - The field 'State' contains the value 'New' that is not in the list of supported values
```

I couldn't find good solution from Microsoft documents . Please be kind enough to share your thoughts (Why this error is throwing) on this.

references :

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/47463/team-member-cant-assign-workitem-getting-error-tha.html
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a8c64056-f204-4b4d-8beb-363e81bc3be7/tf20015-the-field-assigned-to-contains-the-value-xyz-that-is-not-in-the-list-of-supported?forum=tfsgeneral
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696878/fix-the-field-field-contains-a-value-that-is-not-in-the-list-of-suppor

Comment: Is the work item that you're manipulating currently in a state that has a valid transition to *New*?

Comment: Which work item did you manipulate? Are you able to manipulate this work item in UI? Is there a valid transition from New to Close for this work item?

Comment: Hi @CeceDong-MSFT , Yes we can manipulate workitem from UI. and we just can see Active and Resolved option available. Ideally there should be "Active" , "New" , "Close" , "resolved" status, since work item is bug type (agile) .  Could you shed some light on whether what  cause led to this issue? Thanks

Comment: Hi @DanielMann, it should be valid transition since I am working with Bug type work item in Agile template. Thanks

Comment: @Lalindu Could you share your rest api? Have you customized the bug work item before? Do you have another team project collection? You could try your rest calls in another team project collection to see what result will you get.

Comment: This is a bit old but I recently ran into this problem as well with a newly created project in a fairly new collection. I have this issue when trying to use a work item template on TFS's website and trying to make it open as "New", and also using the Team extension for Excel.